# Rename keys in reduce function

Tags: javascript

I am essentially receiving data from another API that takes the following structure

```
const ob = {
  "dataOne": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
  ],
};
```

What I was doing what creating a new array which essentially gets each unique type and then does a total count and an individual count of each unique name.

I also have another data set I combine with this but omitted for this question.

The working code I have is

```js
const ob = {
  "dataOne": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
  ],
};

const dataReduced = ob.dataOne.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc[o.type]) {
    acc[o.type] = [
      {
        count: 0,
        'email.success': 0,
        'email.failed': 0,
      },
    ];
  }

  acc[o.type][0].count = (acc[o.type][0].count || 0) + 1;
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(dataReduced);
```

What I can't figure out however, because it is matching on `email.success` is how to rename these in my final output.  I essentially want to remove the `email.` part.

So instead, the `console.log` should be

```
{
  Type 1: [{
  count: 2,
  failed: 1,
  success: 1
}],
  Type 2: [{
  count: 1,
  failed: 0,
  success: 1
}],
  Type 3: [{
  count: 1,
  failed: 0,
  success: 1
}]
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `acc[o.type][0][o.name.replace('email.', '')] = ~~acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;` and change the default `acc` properties accordingly or remove them.

Comment: Why do you want these result properties (`Type 1`, ...) to have an *array* as value, when those arrays will always have exactly 1 element? What is the additional value of the array wrapper??

Comment: `if (!acc[o.type]) {` is very bad practice btw. if you want to know a key exists in your object then use `if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(o.type)) {`

Comment: I could do this without the array wrapper, thought it would be easier to manage.  What is the alternative?

Comment: make `acc[o.type] = [{count: 0,success: 0,failed: 0,}]` and `acc[o.type][0][o.name.replace('email.', '')] = acc[o.type][0][o.name.replace('email.', '')] + 1;` as Lain mentioned

Comment: also array wrapper is not needed. just `acc[o.type] = {count: 0,success: 0,failed: 0}` and remove the `[0]`s in the logic below

Comment: How would I replace the array wrapper?

Comment: @TTBox checkout the the comment above yours

Comment: If you add it as an answer I can accept it, can't seem to accept comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```js
const ob = {
  "dataOne": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
  ],
};

const dataReduced = ob.dataOne.reduce((acc, o) => {
const name = o.name.replace('email.', '')
  if (!acc[o.type]) {
    acc[o.type] = [
      {
        count: 0,
        'success': 0,
        'failed': 0,
      },
    ];
  }

  acc[o.type][0].count = (acc[o.type][0].count || 0) + 1;
  acc[o.type][0][name] = acc[o.type][0][name] + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(dataReduced);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've no clue why the console output is actually in your Browser console and not in this JS Constainer, but here, no reduce, but I don't even see the reason why a reduce would be better here:

```js
var arr = [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "email.success"
    },
];

var result = [];
for (var o of arr) {
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(o.type)) {
        var newObj = {
            count: 1,
            failed: 0,
            success: 0,
        };
        if (o.name.indexOf('failed') !== -1) {
            newObj.failed++;
        }
        if (o.name.indexOf('success') !== -1) {
            newObj.success++;
        }
        result[o.type] = [newObj];
    } else {
        result[o.type][0].count++;
        if (o.name.indexOf('failed') !== -1) {
            result[o.type][0].failed++;
        }
        if (o.name.indexOf('success') !== -1) {
            result[o.type][0].success++;
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this using the for in loop:

```
for(let elem in dataReduced){
  dataReduced[elem][0]['success'] = dataReduced[elem][0]['email.success'];
  dataReduced[elem][0]['failed'] = dataReduced[elem][0]['email.failed'];
  delete dataReduced[elem][0]['email.success'];
  delete dataReduced[elem][0]['email.failed'];
}
```